# How do I calculate totals based on Dropdown ranges in Google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

This is my table:

```
Item | Person | Price
Shoes | John | $25
Clothes | John | $25
Pants | John | $50
Bags | Sarah | $50
Watch | Sarah | $150
Aftershave | John | $15
```

The Person table I have managed to make it a dropdown following a tutorial.

I know want another column called totals that will work out the total based on the user:

```
Total Sarah:
Total John:
```

It should dynamically find ALL `Sarah` for example and update the total. I have tried using `sumif` but how can I do a `sumif` if all rows in a selected column match the total

This is my sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13MwyK-Suvvg9LfvzFcW-ojL9ilvb5OKCFjQwXgI4h70/edit?usp=sharing

I also tried

`=query(sum(B:B,"count * where B ='John'" ,-1))` and

`=sum(query(B:B, "select B where B='John'")+query(C:C, "select B,C where B='John'"))`

Comment: can you please make your googlesheets open to public so that we can refer your link while reading the solutions. Thanks

Comment: I'm sorry but the sheet received spam and it was a headache to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please clear columns  F:G and in F1:

```
=query(A2:C30,"select B, sum(C) group by B")
```

In G9: `=sum(G2:G6)` and format to suit.

Comment: Thank you, I found this solution the cleanest and simplest. A little like mySQL. I love the fact you simply just group the column and get the total. Pretty clean solution

Answer (score 2):

For Google Sheets only:

`={QUERY({A:C},"select Col2, sum(Col3) where Col2 <> '' group by Col2");"Total",SUM(C:C)}`

## How it works

1. use array `{}` to convert range `A:C` to array `{A:C}`. This is made in order to use `Col1, Col2...` notation in `query`. I prefer this because range letters `A, B, C` may change ant this will cause crash of formula.
2. use query to get the sum.

```
# Syntax
QUERY(data, query, [headers])

# data = The range of cells to perform the query on.
```

You can refer [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) or [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
4. use arrays `{array; value,calue}` to combine the formula. Here's the [link to documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en).

> **Commas:** Separate columns to help you write a row of data in an array. For example, `={"Total",SUM(C:C)}` would place the `Total` in the first cell and the `Sum of C column` in the cell to the right in a new column.

> **Semicolons:** Separate rows to help you write a column of data in an array. For example, `={QUERY; TOTAL}` would place all the queries in the row and then total in the cell below in a new row

Comment: Can you explain please?

Comment: Thanks for that, really helped, gave plus one!